# Filter issue on table with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gb1n2t9/4/)

I got a table built with `ng-repeat`. I'd like to apply a `| filter` on it. It seems to work, however the filtered row isn't the good one.

For example :

If you type `differed` on the search bar , you will get

`DIFFERED  1`

while

`DIFFERED` has `5` as value.

How can I solve it ?

Note that I would like to keep this table structure and not having all the headers horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that filtering will reduce your list, so your `$index` will be always zero, thus accesing the list with `parameter_list[$index]` will return you the first item.

You should `<input type="text" ng-model="parameter.value" class="form-control">` instead

Using parameter you will access the correct item of your filtered list

Answer (score 1):

Use `parameter.value` instead of `parameter_list[$index].value`.